# Object directory in Makefile.am

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, automake

My current Makefile.am looks something like this:

```
bin_PROGRAMS = MyProgram

AM_CPPFLAGS = -I../shared 

MyProgram_SOURCES = main.cpp Source1.cpp ../shared/Source2.cpp

clean : clean-am
        rm -f *~
        rm -f DEADJOE

distclean: distclean-am
        rm -f *~
        rm -f DEADJOE
        rm -f Makefile
        rm -f *log
```

This creates all the .o files in the current directory. How can I specify a different object directory in a Makefile.am? I failed to find this in the GNU documentation, although I am sure it must be there somewhere.

Comment: Do you specifically need a separate object directory or would using an entirely separate build directory be enough? That is make a `build` (or whatever) directory next to (or under or whatever) the source directory and run `configure` from there. That should put all the configured/built files in that directory instead of the source directory I believe.

Comment: That idea defeats the object of not having these temporary .o files clutter the source directory. In a normal Makefile I usually do something like prefix the source files (with ./obj) and then add the ./obj path on the left hand side of the target(s).

Comment: I'm confused, how does using an entirely separate directory for all build-related objects defeat the goal of not having the `.o` files clutter the source directory?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this in Makefile.am.  This approach is not generally supported by autoconf and automake at all.

Instead, Automake supports configuring and building outside the source tree.  So in your current tree, "make distclean", then:

```
mkdir ../build
cd ../build
../src/configure
make
```